# ElvisStealer from Effective Java

Tags: java, serialization, singleton, effective-java

Here is the class stealing reference to a copy of a singleton while singleton is deserialized.

```
public class ElvisStealer implements Serializable {

    static Elvis impersonator;
    private Elvis payload;

    private Object readResolve() {
        // Save a reference to the "unresolved" Elvis instance
        impersonator = payload;
        // Return an object of correct type for favorites field
        return new String[] { "A Fool Such as I" };
    }
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
    
}
```

My questions are:

1. Where and how exactly is a copy of Elvis object reference aquired? This part does not say much about that.

`// Save a reference to the "unresolved" Elvis instance impersonator = payload;`

In other words, how can child object's `readResolve` access parent object reference?

2. To make ElvisStealer work I have to modify serialized data by replacing singleton instance field of type `String[]` (in that case) with ElvisStealer instance. In the book singleton contains a non `transient` `String[]` instance field and that field is replaced with ElvisStealer instance in serialized stream. Then when that field is deserialized, `ObjectInputStream` sees that this field is of type ElvisStealer and it invokes `readResolve` from ElvisStealer class. My questions are: why JVM don't give an error parsing such field knowing that there should be String instead of ElvisStealer and secondly why JVM invokes `readResolve` from ElvisStealer class knowing that there should be `String[]`, not ElvisStealer.
3. Why ElvisStealer contains an instance field of type Elvis in addition to static field? Shouldn't be static field enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deserialization will always start with fresh instances conjured out of thin air and bytes from the `ObjectInputStream`.

After that step you have all new instances like so:

```
Elvis(new).favoriteSongs = ElvisStealer(new)
ElvisStealer(new).payload = Elvis(new)   // same elvis, circular reference
```

Then in step 2, deserialization uses the `readResolve` methods of those instances to "resolve" the preliminary deserialized objects to their final form. However it starts with the inner `ElvisStealer`.

```
Elvis(new).favoriteSongs = ElvisStealer(new).readResolve()
=> Elvis(new).favoriteSongs = String[] { .... }
```

Next step is to resolve the `Elvis` instance

```
result = Elvis(new).readResolve()
=> result = Elvis(INSTANCE)
```

The correct type (`String[]` instead of the actually invalid `ElvisStealer`)  is only required to be present after the `readResolve` step.

Having this "invalid" stage inbetween is useful. You can declare in the  `writeReplace` method that you want a different object serialized instead, then in that object's `readResolve` method have code that produces an object of the right type.

E.g. when you have

```
class ComplexThing implements Serializable {
    private Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return new SimpleHiddenReplacement();
    }
}
private class SimpleHiddenReplacement implements Serializable {
    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return new ComplexThing();
    }
}
```

You can pass `ComplexThing` to an `ObjectOutputStream` and you'll get back a `ComplexThing` from the `ObjectInputStream`, but under the hood, the bytes those streams operate on on are actually the representation of a `SimpleHiddenReplacement`.

The elvis stealing attack steals the freshly created `Elvis` before it's `readResolve` method (= it's unresolve) had a chance to replace (resolve) it.

---

> `ElvisStealer(new).payload = Elvis(new)`. Where does that happen?  I see only the declaration of a payload variable, but it is not initialized in any way.

The book says

> First, write a “stealer” class that has [..] an instance field that refers to the serialized singleton in which the stealer “hides.” In the serialization stream, replace the singleton’s nontransient field with an instance of the stealer.

This setup happens in the form of a crafted `byte[] serializedForm`. It is a fake serialized form of an `Elvis` object, which unlike normal serialized Elvises contains the stealer with a backreference to the `Elvis` object.

> Secondly, shouldn't the `static impersonator` be enough?

No, serialization doesn't do static variables, only instance fields. This attack relies on initialization of the variables by the deserialization and deserialization does that because there is a value in the serialized form.

Comment: Thanks, that cleares up 2nd question. Going back to 1st and 3rd question. You wrote "`ElvisStealer(new).payload = Elvis(new)`   // same elvis, circular reference". Where does that happen in book? I see only declaration of `payload` variable, but it is not initialized in any way. Secondly, shouldn't be static variable `impersonator` enough? Instead of initializing `payload`, `impersonator` could be initialized with value used to initialize `payload`?

Comment: @ctomek added a bit to the question. Does that help?

Comment: Ah, ok, I missed the part about initializing `payload` in serialization stream. I have only seen that mechanism as replacing original `String` instance variable with `ElvisStealer` object and I didn't know when `payload` is initialized in code. But it is not initialized in code, but in serialization stream, by pasting original `Elvis` singleton as `payload` value. Is it right? I was confused because book don't describe that clearly.

Comment: To end that topic, please confirm that my description is correct. ; )